# Google webfonts iOS and IE special characters

Tags: ios, fonts, mobile-safari, webfonts

Using this webfont

http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto+Condensed

iOS devices seem to be having troubles with special characters. Please see image below.
Mac safari, chrome and other browsers seem to be fine

http://s12.postimg.org/56v8jc2zh/fail.jpg

PS: IE also seems to have same problem

Thanks

Comment: Live web: http://www.webiz.cz/x/vivafina